# Relative strengths/weaknesses of Demons and Undead

Tags: exalted

On a general rule, what are the relative strengths and weaknesses of Underworld creatures (ghosts, skeletons, Abyssals) versus Malfeas creatures (demons, Infernals) in a combat situation?

Does this change whether the fight happens in Creation, in the Underworld, or in Malfeas?

Note that I am strictly asking about straight mechanical advantages - not "there are more of X than Y" or "X has better infrastructure than Y", but more "X is immune to Y's charms" or "X's charms are more effective against Y".

Answer (score 1):

Ghosts tend to have smaller essence pools when compared to demons and Exalted. Their charms are also generally less dangerous.
They often do not have access to martial arts charms, and even if they do it's limited to terrestrial martial arts.
And in creation they are generally immaterial.
They can pull some nasty tricks out of their hat using various poltergeist-like powers but that's about it.
And finally it's pretty tricky for a ghost to regain essence.
They can learn first circle necromancy, but onlyif they start hearing whispers, which is often very bad news for a ghost in the long term.

Demons, they're too varied to give you a clear cut answer. First circle demons are good entry-level combatants. Blood apes and the like can provice nice crunchy targets early on in an exalted campaign but they'll quickly turn in to general rank and file mooks like most low-level supernaturals.
Second circle demons are much more dangerous. They've got the attack pools to force most Exalted characters to use their perfect defenses. And they've got quite a lot of essence in their pools.
They use the same charms(mechanically) as spirits. Some have perfect defenses most don't. But they almost all have got a lot of soak and health levels.
There's no practical diffrence between fighting them in Malfeas, Creation or the Underworld.
They regain essence normally in all the realms except the underworld.

Abyssals, they're as dangerous as the solar exalted. A few survival charms work only in the underworld as opposed to their solar mirrors.
They respire essence naturally in the Underworld and have to rely on Hearthstones or their feeding charms everywhere ese.